# Unable to set the screen resolution above 1920x1080 (want smaller texts on large screen)

Tags: display, display-resolution

I am running 20.04 LTS with one monitor and my laptop screen: a 27" Acer .

The text on the high-resolution monitor is too big and I want to reduce the size.

I tried using the "Screen Display" setting screen to change the scaling, but it was already at 100%. I have no idea why they have chosen only multiples of 100% as available options, but this type of UI scaling isn't what I'm after. I want to use the monitors with smaller text size, i'm using Acer Nitro QG1 27" 1920x1080 resolution monitor, in the settings I can't seem to increase the resolution anymore, I tried using `xrandr` commands:

```
 1196  xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_40.00"  201.00  2560 2720 2984 3408  1440 1443 1448 
 1476 +hsync +vsync
 1197  xrandr --addmode HDMI-A-0 2560x1440_40.00
 1198  xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 2560x1440_40.00 --verbose
```

But this didn't seem to help. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused why you tried to used xrandr to set a higher resolution when you say you want a lower one. 2560x1400 > 1920x1080

Comment: Sorry, I meant higher, corrected it now!